# Excess elements in scalar initializer, error I keep getting in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that gets the majority element in array. However I get this weird error. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_majority_element(arr) {
    int length = sizeof(arr);
    return length;
}

int main()
{
    int input = { 12, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 1, 2 };
    printf(find_majority_element(input));
}
```

When executing, I get this error:

```
$gcc -o main *.c
main.c: In function ‘find_majority_element’:
main.c:3:5: warning: type of ‘arr’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 int find_majority_element(arr) {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:23: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
     int input = { 12, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 1, 2 };
                       ^
$main
timeout: the monitored command dumped core
sh: line 1: 176437 Segmentation fault      timeout 10s main
```

Why do I keep getting this error? Right now, all I'm doing is getting and printing the length. Nothing more. I tried a different compiler and it said there was a segmentation fault, whatever that means.

Comment: You tried a different compiler? So, if you get errors you think the compiler is faulty, not your code??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not weird. It is expected. `int x = {2}` this is valid anything other than this inside `{}` when used in RHS of `=` in initialization -  it is Undefined behavior.  Here you tried to initialize an `int` variable with more than one value.

What will correct it? `int x[]={1,2,3,4}` yes this is right - initializing an array with 4 elements.

And what else? When you pass an array to a function it is converted to pointer to the first element. Applying `sizeof` to it won't give you the length of the array.

There is still more. In `main()` even if you did what you did in other function - it's still wrong.

```
printf("Length of array is %zu\n",sizeof(x)/sizeof x[0]);
```

This will give you the length of the array. This is the correct way to get it. (There is one case where `sizeof(x)` will return the length of the array correctly - that is when `x` is `char` array).

The code will be something like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_majority_element(size_t len, int* arr) {
    ...    
    return someIntVar;
}

int main(void)
{
    int input[] = { 12, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 9, 2, 2, 1, 2 };
    size_t len = sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);
    printf("%d\n", find_majority_element(len, input));
    return 0;
}
```

*Your compiler is right* complaining you about this.

Standard mentions this :-

From [6.7.9p11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p11)

> **The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, *optionally enclosed in braces*.** The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

By not having this - you made it undefined behavior. This is not a single expression that you gave earlier - for initializing `int`. That's why it's undefined behavior.

---

Also the first error message you have - parameters without any type information is considered to be of type int. Your way of defining the function is a reminder of the K&R notation of function definition.

```
int find_majority_element(arr) 
int *arr;
{
    int length = sizeof(arr);
    return length;
}
```

This is almost obsolete now.

Comment: And I thought it must be a compiler error. Some standard quote please?

Comment: @user202729.: standard quote Regarding the undefined error part?

Comment: Why is it even valid syntax? <-- that.

Comment: @user202729.: Edited.

Comment: ... Ok, I somehow forgot that not-strictly-conforming program may be able to compile. So are wrong programs. Sorry.

Comment: @user202729.: It complained and most of the cases the undefined behavior boils down to assigning the first value in the list to the `int`.

Comment: Should you discuss the K&R notation in the original function definition?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler.: I should? Those are age old and I don't know what to say about those. Those are even valid these days?

Comment: They're still part of C11, but the type must be specified (no 'implicit `int`').  It should not be used.  It was sloppy C when the standard was first produced. It is inexcusable in code written in this millennium.  But it would explain the first compiler message.